# The binary file that I build from Visual Studio project flashes then disappear on Windows 7

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, binaryfiles, snare

I was building Snare project, an open source EventLog Agent, in Visual Studio 2013. The project compiled without any error, but when I run SnareCore.exe as an administrator, it flashed and then disappeared. The binary file that I build is 469 KB and the binary file that they have on SourceForge is 1.02 MB. I am trying to build the project by myself with the purpose of modifying Snare in the future to meet my personal goals. Does anyone has any idea what's going wrong here?

Comment: run it from the command line to see its output.

Comment: Or press Ctrl+F5 instead.